# MySQL: Substring before a digit

Tags: mysql, regex, substring, locate

I have a column of type varchar containing chars and numbers. Ex: "ABC123", "XY2"

I want to find the substring before a number. Output:"ABC", "XY"

I went through this post  [Finding number position in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135464/finding-number-position-in-string). But it looked tedious. Is there any elegant way to do this?

I tried to use Locate() as in this post [MySQL: Use REGEX to extract string (select REGEX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string), but it does not take regexp.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have any good built-in functions for doing this. The method in the the first question you linked to is as good as it gets. If you want something less verbose, write a UDF.

Comment: Thanks. I am left with no choice then.

Comment: it can be achieved by MySQL 'user' function or, at least, you can extract a string without digits by means of backend script