# add integer from string consisted of character and integer having the same character

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql table.

```
name   |  column
bob11  |  value
bob22  |  value
red12  |  value
bam22  |  value
```

What i want to do is to add the numbers 11 and 22 because the name bob is just the same. I want to output it this way together with the other names.

```
name   |  column
bob33  |  value
red12  |  value
bam22  |  value
```

I know already how to get the column with the same value by this code.

```
"SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
```

But i don't know how to do the operation. Any idea would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do that in SQL alone. You could strip the integer and the name in PHP, add the integers, and then append back to the name.

Comment: learn the `substr` command.  Sorry but your query is a little general and that's the best I can give you

Comment: That's why we should use the 1NF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)

Answer (score 0):

If the part before the number is always 3 characters long, you can use `LEFT()` and `SUBSTR()` to extract the prefix and number, then use `CONCAT()` and `SUM()` to combine them.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(name, 3), SUM(SUBSTR(name, 4))) AS name, `column`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LEFT(name, 3);
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7264e3/4)

If not, you'll need to write a function that returns the position of the numeric suffix, and use that instead of hard-coding `3`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(name, number_pos(name)-1), SUM(SUBSTR(name, number_pos(name)))) AS name, `column`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LEFT(name, number_pos(name)-1)
```

See [Finding number position in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135464/finding-number-position-in-string) for ways to find the position of the number.

Comment: no it is not, just used the above names for example.

Comment: I've updated the answer to say how to do it with a variable-length prefix.